# Move .Net application (full .Net framework) to aws?

Tags: .net, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2

I have a .Net application which was scheduled to be run periodically to process text Microsoft office files. I need to move it to aws. Besides running it in a Windows EC2, what's the other approaches to run it on aws?

It seems ECS only accepts Linux docker. Is Elastic Beanstalk suitable to run scheduled processes?

Comment: ECS accepts windows containers since late last year. https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/compute/running-windows-containers-on-amazon-ecs/

Comment: Interesting, the AWS toolkit for visual studio doesn't show the publish to ecs for the project created for Windows docker.